# Google AdMobs Xamarin CrossPlatform

Tags: firebase, xamarin, cross-platform, ads

I am working on a cross-platform app and trying to implement google ad mobs, but google and firebase do not include an instructions list for Xamarin, only for Swift. Any ideas of what would be best to add ads?

Thank you!

Comment: If you google google admobs xamarin tutorial, you will find many examples like [Xamarin Forms Integration with Google Admob](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1275283/Xamarin-Forms-Integration-with-Google-Admob) and [AdMob-Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/juucustodio/AdMob-Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: Let me see if the nuget package works because every tutorial I have tried have been recently deprecated, which is super frustrating.

Comment: Have a try and if it is working on your side, you can share the solution here:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following either of these tutorials will work.  Just change the iOS code, in AppDelegate to

`MobileAds.Configure("Your App ID");

Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
MobileAds.SharedInstance.Start(completionHandler);
MobileAds.SharedInstance.RequestConfiguration.TestDeviceIdentifiers = new string[] {"kGADSimulatorID", "Your Device ID" };`

to find your device ID, leave the test device identifiers blank, and the console will spit it out at you.

Comment: Ok, you can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem.